# next iteration while running a script

Tags: vbscript, qtp

in a script when error comes i am just using "EXITGLOBALITERATION" command but its not going to the next iteration ....Is there any other alternative for this??

Comment: Some code would really help here as it seems from the two kind souls who have already tried to help that we may not be getting what you are trying to do. Please edit your question and add the pertinent code to make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 2):

QTP's documentation has this to say about `ExitGlobalIteration`:

> This statement is obsolete. Use the ExitTest Statement instead. The ExitTest statement supplies all the functionality of the ExitRun statement and is equally applicable for both QuickTest tests and Quality Center business process tests.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like he is on about QTP!

I believe you should be using ExitActionIteration but without having an idea of the setup of your test script its hard to best know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to test after each command for an error, something like this

```
On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To 10
  'Command1
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    'Command2
     If Err.Number = 0 Then
       'Command3
     End If
  End If
Next
```